How to use vscode debugger for web3 development?
For Web3 development, it's necessary to have wallet extensions like MetaMask to test the DApps with it. How can I say vscode debugger to use my browsers user with its all extensions and don't use it as incognito window?
My current launch.json file:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s",
                "action": "debugWithChrome"
            }
        }
    ]
}


VS Code is not using Incognito mode, rather it's using a fresh user profile without any extensions installed or so. And, that happens because VS Code starts Chrome with a custom data-dir.
You can read more about this on this Chromium blog.
So, in order to disable this custom data-dir behaviour, you need to set the userDataDir field as false in the corresponding item/object of configurations array of your launch.json file, like:

"configurations": [
        …
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "userDataDir": false // to disable VSCode from running in a custom data-dir
        },
        …
]


